# How to use visual studio 2015 to automatically include third part library?

Tags: visual-studio

I have some third part libraries such as OpenGL library etc. If I want to use third part library, I have to configure VC++ directory every time in visual studio 2015?[image]

Does exist a way that when I create a new projection that visual studio will automatically include third part library?